# Angular 8 read boolean value from another component to root component

Tags: angular, boolean, components, angular8, eventemitter

I'm still learning every bit about Angular 8 and how it works. I have one thing lately that's been stumping me. We have two areas of the app that changes a lot of the navigation menu options and I want to make sure that it changes depending on whether or not a certain value is true or false.

I have learned about @Input and @Output and Eventemitter however usually that's normally read from the component itself. Whereas, the navigation isn't reading from any components, and all our components are coming through router-outlet (which I am not completely sure how it works)

Essentially app.component.html is:

```
<nav class="app-menu">
 <ul class="this-menu" *ngIf="!isAlt"></ul>
 <ul class="alternate-menu" *ngIf="isAlt"></ul>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

By default isAlt will be false, until you hit pages wrapped in a specific container that change the value of isAlt to be true. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a state service for your project. This service can keep check of your variables. You can put an observable of the state service variable. Therefore, whenever a page that you want is hit, update the state variable. This will update the variable at the state level and the state service will emit the value of that component to all the subscribers.

Here is the working demo of state service: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-state-service?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstate.service.ts

Comment: Sorry for the late reply: I understand what's being done here, however, I am unsure how to apply it to just a boolean. Would this be overkill for just reading 0 or 1, yes or no, true or false?